# Android: Two dimensional ArrayList Help

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Currently I have my code putting user input into a one-dimensional ArrayList, but I would like to put them into a two dimensional ArrayList and am having some trouble.

Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private static final String TAG = "Matrix";
   static ArrayList<EditText> columnEditTexts;




   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.matrix);
       View doneButton = findViewById(R.id.done_button);
       doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

       for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
           TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
           TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           EditText column = new EditText(this);
           for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++){
               table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
               column = new EditText(this);
               column.setId(i);
               row.addView(column);
               columnEditTexts.add(column);
           }
           table.addView(row);
       }



   }
```

Comment: and what, exactly, is the trouble?

Comment: Right now it's only putting the EditTexts into a single dimension array. How would I put them into a two dimensional array?

Comment: Could you add to the question what you hope to achieve by storing these in a two dimensional array?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to Multiply two matrices together (for example http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/MatrixMultiply.shtml).  I have another activity for the second matrix that is just like this one and then a results activity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you need to first create a two dimensional ArrayList. To do that, you need to create an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>> arrayOfEditTexts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>>();
```

So then you loop will become something along these lines (assuming I understand what you are trying to do):

```
for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
       columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();
       TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
       TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
       EditText column = new EditText(this);
       for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++) {               
           column = new EditText(this);
           column.setId(i);
           row.addView(column);
           columnEditTexts.add(column);
       }
       table.addView(row);
       arrayOfEditTexts.add(columnEditTexts);
   }
```

Comment: This is close but seems to keep adding identical ArrayLists. For a 2x3 matrix I would like the ArrayList to be  [1 2 3]
                                             [4 5 6].
Currently it is storing it as [1 2 3 4 5 6]
                              [1 2 3 4 5 6]

Comment: There is a problem in your for loop then. The structure of the ArrayList remains the same, the problem is in how you populate it.