# Working with 2D array in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-studio

I am new in android studio,
I am working with listItem. below is some of my code

```
String[] items = {
            "1 st",
            "2 nd",
            "3 rd",
            "4 th"};

    titleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem,titleList);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Above code working fine. but i want work with more then 1 Array tree I want to work with 2D array but i can't understand what to do here is my new code I tried. but failed

```
String[][] items = {

             {"1 st","12 th Sept"},
             {"2 nd","13 th Sept"},
             {"3 rd","14 th Sept"},
             {"4 th","15 th Sept"},
};

titleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items[0]));
dateList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items[1]));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem,titleList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.date,dateList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: See if this link can help you somehow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176512/android-two-dimensional-arraylist-help

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You should change the order of your `2d array` like below. But it will still not work (See next point)

```
String[][] items = {
         {"1 st", "2 nd", "3 rd", "4 th"},
{"12 th Sept", "13 th Sept", "14 th Sept", "15 th Sept"},
    };
```

**2)** Below, in the first line, your `adapter` is refering to the `ArrayAdapter` with `titlelist` and in next line, you are changing the **same** `adapter object` to point to `datelist` `ArrayAdapter`.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem,titleList);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.date,dateList);
```

So, after 2nd line, your adapter is no longer pointing to `titlelist` ArrayAdapter. It is referring to `datelist` ArrayAdapter only. Actually, it can never hold both `datelist` and `titlelist` together.

**What's the right way then?**

Create a model `class` containing `title` and `date` like below -

```
class YourModel {
String title;
String date;
}
```

Create an `array` of objects of this model class and pass this array of objects to your custom `adapter`. It's the **only** way. You will have to create custom ArrayAdapter. Learn about it from [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that array instantiation is the correct syntax, but you're creating a 4 x 2 array, when it looks like you want a 2x4 array.

Have you tried:

```
String[][] items = {
         {"1 st", "2 nd", "3 rd", "4 th"},
         {"12 th Sept", "13 th Sept", "14 th Sept", "15 th Sept"},
};
```

Comment: @SUJOYROY Like I said in my answer, it will not work. You have to create custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @SachinAggarwal I visited your suggested page in your answer. But i can't understand what to do with my project. I am new in android studio

Comment: @SUJOYROY Actually, you will have to learn about custom ArrayAdapters. Need much better tutorial. Watch this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK4gQ2aOpw0

Comment: This is for image+text..in your case, it will be title + date in model class.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-dimensional is an array that contains arrays as elements. Those elements or arrays can both have same length or same number of int values or varying numbers which can break matrix approach.

`int[][] myArray= new array[3][2];` means this is an array that contains 3 arrays with 2 int values(values are 0 by default).

```
myArray[0] = {0,0};
myArray[1] = {0,0};
myArray[2] = {0,0};
```

Or you can interpret this as 3x2 matrix with 3 rows and 2 columns
You can also declare 2 dimensional arrays that contains 1 dimensional arrays with varying sizes too.

```
int[][] otherArray= new array[3][];
otherArray[0] = new array[3];
otherArray[1] = new array[4];
otherArray[2] = new array[5];
```

Or you can assign initial values to elements.

```
otherArray[0] = {1,2,3};
otherArray[1] = {4,5,6,7};
otherArray[2] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now you can get otherArray[2][4] which returns 5 but you can't get otherArray[1][4] since it does not exist and returns IndexOutOfBoundException. 2 dimensional arrays are arrays that contain arrays.